# Save Value in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, save, return-value

I've created a settings menu. By opening the menu the method load will be performed. So the menu knows what checkbox and radiobutton was selected:

```
static void load() {
    testAllPagesHaveSameRotation.setSelected(PREFS.getBoolean("check1", false));
    testAllPagesHaveSameSize.setSelected(PREFS.getBoolean("check2", false));
    testAllFontsAreEmbedded.setSelected(PREFS.getBoolean("check3", false));
    testContent.setSelected(PREFS.getBoolean("check4", false));

    radioButtonCm.setSelected(PREFS.getBoolean("radio1", false));
    radioButtonInch.setSelected(PREFS.getBoolean("radio2", false));
}
```

By clicking the save button the method the method store will be performed.

```
static void store() {
            PREFS.putBoolean("check1", testAllPagesHaveSameRotation.isSelected());
            PREFS.putBoolean("check2", testAllPagesHaveSameSize.isSelected());
            PREFS.putBoolean("check3", testAllFontsAreEmbedded.isSelected());
            PREFS.putBoolean("check4", testContent.isSelected());

            PREFS.putBoolean("radio1", radioButtonCm.isSelected());
            PREFS.putBoolean("radio2", radioButtonInch.isSelected());
}
```

But I have a **JTextfield** and the entered value as **String** in the settings menu too. How I can implement it in those methods?

```
..
JTextField toleranceField;
String tolerance;
..
```

I've already tried this:

```
        PREFS.put("check5", toleranceField.getText());
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Your solution should work. Do you get an error message is the value just not stored? What code do you when filling the textfield in the load method?

Comment: Well, the problem is that with the store method I write the values in the registry with the values "check1..." and so on.
Each time when I close completely the settings menu and run it again the pc knows what is in the registry and just read the values and put them again in the settings menu. 

But how I can do it with the String tolerance that I enter...? :(

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void store() {

            ......

            PREFS.put("check6", toleranceField.getText());

}

static void load() {

    ....

    toleranceField.setText(PREFS.get("check6", "default string value"));
}
```

If the backing store is inaccessible or not valid value is specified for "check6" then the default "default string value" will be returned and set as text for the JTextField. The default value can also be NULL if needed. Try this and check:

1. If default value returned -> backing store unaccessible or value not set
2. Exception thrown:
   **IllegalStateException** - if this node (or an ancestor) has been removed with the removeNode()       method or **NullPointerException** - if value is null